# Rewrite avg without subquery

Tags: oracle, subquery, average

How I can rewrite this query without subquery??

```
select i.invoice_number, i.invoice_total 
  from invoices i 
 where i.invoice_total>(select avg(payment_total) 
                          from invoices);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a variant for you..using only one select on 10g+ and without a cartesian self join :)

```
SQL> select avg(payment_total)
  2    from invoices;

AVG(PAYMENT_TOTAL)
------------------
               5.4

SQL> select invoice_number, invoice_total, payment_total
  2    from invoices
  3  model return updated rows
  4  dimension by (row_number() over (order by 1) rn,
  5                case when invoice_total > avg(payment_total) over () then 1 else 2 end a)
  6  measures (invoice_total, invoice_number, payment_total)
  7  rules  (
  8     invoice_number[any, 1] = invoice_number[cv(rn), 1]
  9  )
 10   order by 1;

INVOICE_NUMBER INVOICE_TOTAL PAYMENT_TOTAL
-------------- ------------- -------------
             6             6             1
             7             7             8
             8             8             4
             9             9             7
            10            10             6
```

"return updated rows" .. we only return rows that we touched. We mark each row as to whether it exceeded the average with `case when invoice_total > avg(payment_total) over () then 1 else 2 end a`. I.e. those rows over average have `a` set to `1`. then we just tickle the rows with `1` by `invoice_number[any, 1] = invoice_number[cv(rn), 1]` (ie don't change any data..just update it to itself).

compared to your original query:

```
SQL> select i.invoice_number, i.invoice_total , i.payment_total
  2    from invoices i
  3   where i.invoice_total>(select avg(payment_total)
  4                            from invoices)
  5   order by 1;

INVOICE_NUMBER INVOICE_TOTAL PAYMENT_TOTAL
-------------- ------------- -------------
             6             6             1
             7             7             8
             8             8             4
             9             9             7
            10            10             6
```

Answer (score 2):

Only one SELECT :-)

```
select i1.invoice_number, i1.invoice_total 
from invoices i1, invoices i2 
group by i1.invoice_number, i1.invoice_total 
having i1.invoice_total > avg(i2.payment_total)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  invoice_number,
  invoice_total
from (
  select 
    invoice_number,
    invoice_total ,
    avg(payment_total) over () avg_payment_total
  from
    invoices)
where
  invoice_total>avg_payment_total;
```

Comment: But you still use subquery to slove this problem(

Comment: That's an in-line view.

Comment: Is it possible to slove this task without any view? Just join?

Comment: How about with a common table expression? Does that count as a subquery?

Comment: Im not sure, It needs to use "Select" once!

Comment: @Yuliya: why don't you want to use the derived table ("inline view")?

Comment: its not fare, in this way i need to use more that one SELECT. There is a condition: only one SELECT. Im looking for solution that has only one select :((

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple ways to do it.  I don't guarantee your professor will accept them.

For our first alternative, you first create a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION AVG_PAYMENT_TOTAL_FUNC RETURN NUMBER IS
  nAvg_payment_total  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT AVG(PAYMENT_TOTAL)
    INTO nAvg_payment_total
    FROM INVOICES;

  RETURN nAvg_payment_total;
END AVG_PAYMENT_TOTAL_FUNC;
```

then you use the function in a query:

```
select i.invoice_number, i.invoice_total 
  from invoices i 
  where i.invoice_total > AVG_PAYMENT_TOTAL_FUNC;
```

The second alternative would be to create a view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW AVG_PAYMENT_TOTAL_VIEW AS
  SELECT AVG(PAYMENT_TOTAL) AS AVG_PAYMENT_TOTAL
    FROM INVOICES;
```

and then your query becomes

```
SELECT i.INVOICE_NUMBER,
       i.INVOICE_TOTAL,
       t.AVG_PAYMENT_TOTAL
  FROM INVOICES i
  CROSS JOIN AVG_PAYMENT_TOTAL_VIEW t;
```

Short of something like this I can't see a way to accomplish what you've been assigned.  More to the point, I can't picture any reason WHY anyone would care whether there's one or two SELECT keywords in a query.  Requiring that a developer come up with some quirky/geeky/nerdy way to accomplish all the above in a single query with only one SELECT keyword is a waste of time.  There are perfectly reasonable ways to get this done quickly and sensibly; requiring someone to solve the problem otherwise is neither productive or efficient, and is therefore and IMO pointless.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

```
with average as (select avg(payment_total) avgtot
                 from invoices)
select i.invoice_number, i.invoice_total 
  from invoices i 
  ,    average a
 where i.invoice_total>a.avgtot;
```

Comment: a WITh clause is still a sub-query